# Button clicked but nothing happens on webpage(Selenium WebDriver)

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click to "Get Data" button on this website.
https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/currency/archieve_cd.htm

Here's my code. I have solved some of the issues but clicking doesnt work with no error.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:/Users/UserName/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

url = "https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/currency/archieve_cd.htm"
driver.get(url)
 
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='h_filetype']/option[text()='Daily Bhavcopy']").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("date").send_keys('05-01-2021')
time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_id("date").send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE)
time.sleep(2)

element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[class="getdata-button"]').click()
```

After clicking the button a zip file link should appear.Which has to be clicked next.

How to click "Get Data" button? Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

```
url = "https://www1.nseindia.com/archives/cd/bhav/CD_Bhavcopy050121.zip"
driver.get(url)
```

You delete all the rest of the code that exists after this.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='h_filetype']/option[text()='Daily Bhavcopy']").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("date").send_keys('05-01-2021')
time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_id("date").send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE)
time.sleep(2)

element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[class="getdata-button"]').click()
```

`This is the code that you don't need.`

And if you want to make it to Auto Download more data try to make a code that will generate the calendar days and place them here `CD_Bhavcopy050121.zip`

So when you will want to extract the data from `05/01/2019` you will have to change the part of the `html` to this `CD_Bhavcopy050119.zip`

Comment: Have you tried to use the ```driver.find_elemet_by_xpath``` ??

Comment: Doesn't let me either. I think that he knows we are using an automate script and doesn't let us to get the data. I will try another method and i will keep you updated.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Check it out and tell me your results.

Comment: Thanks for this!! But i want "'Daily Bhavcopy'" .This downloads Daily volatility file.Also if you could tell me how you found this.

Comment: Sry i used the wrong link xD! Check it again i updated!

Comment: I found it just by experience man. I had a problem like this before. You always have to think the alternatives. If you just open your browser, click ```get data```, and see the results, if you right-click on the file that has popped up and click the ```copy url``` you will have your link to download the file.

Comment: It doesn't download data for say 010110 which is 01-01-2010.But i can download manually by clicking "Get Data".So i have to solve this only.

Comment: Check if you are changing it correctly. I can download it via the script perfectly.

Comment: In my case if i copy-paste this link ```https://www1.nseindia.com/archives/cd/bhav/CD_NSEUSDINR010110.dbf.zip``` i can download it. But i have noticed that in 2010 they used this ```CD_NSEUSDINR``` instead of this ```CD_Bhavcopy```. So that's why it doesn't download your data.

Comment: they have used this name ```CD_Bhavcopy ..... dbf.zip``` until ```27/10/2010```. Then they changed it to ```CD_Bhavcopy```. So if you try to download ```29/10/2010``` it will be with this new name